# Isomorphisme of measurable space

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Hi,

Can you ,help me to understand this proposition, and it's prrof ?

> Definition 24 is :
>
> A measurable space $(T, \mathcal{T})$ is said to be separable if there
>   existe a sequence $(A_n)$ dans $\mathcal{T}$ which generates
>   $\mathcal{T}$ and $\chi_{A_n}$ separate the points of $T$

Please

Thank you

Comment: What is definition 24? What parts do you not understand?

Comment: for first why $h$ is one to one ? , and after when they proof that if $A\in \mathcal{T}, h(A)\in \mathcal{B}(h(T))$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $h:T\to h(T)$ is a surjection. The fact that $h$ is an injection follows from the fact that $\{1_{A_n}\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ separate points of $T$. That is, if $t\neq s$ then $h(t)\neq h(s)$ since for some $n$ it holds that there exists a separation indicator function, that is $1_{A_n}(t)\neq 1_{A_n}(s)$.

I didn't get your second confusion, could you elaborate?

Comment: ok, ok , thank's ,after that theu say "it remains to prove that ..." , they do this to prove what ? please

Comment: $h$ is an isomorphisme if $h$ is one to one and preserves the structure,olso for $h^{-1}$ right ?

Answer (score 0):

Is true that for each ideal $I,$ $J,$ $K$ and $L$ of a ring $R.$ If $I\cong J$ and $K\cong L$ then $IK\cong JL$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).